# Retrieve the set of used columns in a contour app

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

I have a contour application with an input data-set of which I would like to know which columns are being used by the application. Is there a 'defined' way to achieve this? Either trough the application it self, or for example using the REST API.

Tried looking trough the documentation for contour, and the REST API for foundry with no luck so far.

Comment: At first glance you could look at the schema of the input dataset

Comment: The schema of the dataset shows all columns in the dataset, while I want to know the subset of these, those which are used in the contour.

Comment: your contour application "state" is probably structured as a json. If you look at the networks tab in your browser you should be able to see the "state" as a payload to the autosave network call. You could likely extract the columns from this state